# Android App that starts Web App

Tags: android, browser

I am trying to make a simple app that starts the webbrowser on the right page. Simply enougth I found the code to do it right here on stackoverflow.

But there is a problem, if you open the website threw the app, then click home button and open the app again then nothing happens and the browser does not open.

Does anybody know away to force the browser in the foreground?

Edit: Extend question:

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the MainActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    oWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    oWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());       
    oWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String url = "http://google.com";
    oWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

My problem is with the fullscreen, the Webview does not extend to the hole screen. See the top right:
[image: Not fully extended Webview]

It doesn't really matter on this websites but on other it messes up the views.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

WebView oWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
oWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());       
oWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
oWebView.loadUrl(your_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xml: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//or in code
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

WebView oWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
oWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());       
oWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
oWebView.loadUrl(your_url);

onResume(){
   oWebView.reload();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer it works. The only problem I have with this is that it does not look like in does in the browser. It has wired borders on the side, do you have any tip on how to get away with these?

Comment: Can your post a screenshot? It might be helpful :)

Comment: I extended the answer.